# Implement and train YOLO 3 with Opencv and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, yolo

I want to implement  and train YOLO 3 with my dataset using Opencv and C++, i can't find an example to start with, or a tutorial to explain how to train YOLO  with my own data, all the tutorials i found are in python and don't use Opencv.
Do you have any example, or an explanation to how to code an object detector with YOLO 3, opencv with C++.

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/

Comment: Nice tutorial, thank you